# Element does not update contents

Tags: javascript, html, navigator

Following is the JavaScript code to reveal the Browser details. Its showing no output. Please let me know where I am doing wrong.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var txt;
        txt = "<p>Browser CodeName: " + navigator.appCodeName + "</p>";
        txt+= "<p>Browser Name: " + navigator.appName + "</p>";
        txt+= "<p>Browser Version: " + navigator.appVersion + "</p>";
        txt+= "<p>Cookies Enabled: " + navigator.cookieEnabled + "</p>";
        txt+= "<p>Platform: " + navigator.platform + "</p>";
        txt+= "<p>User-agent header: " + navigator.userAgent + "</p>";

        document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=txt;

      </script>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="example"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep your code in after you have the `example p` and it will run fine.

Something like this will work. But, you should always separate your javascript from HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

</head>

<body>

    <p id="example"></p>
   <script type="text/javascript">

        var txt;
        txt = "<p>Browser CodeName: " + navigator.appCodeName + "</p>";
        txt+= "<p>Browser Name: " + navigator.appName + "</p>";
        txt+= "<p>Browser Version: " + navigator.appVersion + "</p>";
        txt+= "<p>Cookies Enabled: " + navigator.cookieEnabled + "</p>";
        txt+= "<p>Platform: " + navigator.platform + "</p>";
        txt+= "<p>User-agent header: " + navigator.userAgent + "</p>";

        document.getElementById("example").innerHTML=txt;

      </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are running the Javascript before the `example` div element exists. Run it later (= at the end of the document).

Comment: Y NO ONE MENTIONS `DOMContentLoaded` EVENT?

Comment: @jAndy because jQuery has made me lazy and I'm not sure what a non-jQuery, cross-browser DOMContentLoaded solution would look like - IIRC, it was very complicated to do. Do provide an answer though, it'll get my upvote

Comment: @Juhana: true. However, all browser vendors do implement it in their latest version (at least). So its pretty cross browser.

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing the element while it does not exist yet. The reason for this is that the element is defined later than your script. You'll get `null` for the `getElementById` call, which results in a `TypeError` for accessing `.innerHTML`.

Use `window.onload`:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var txt;
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Nooo not `onload`, it'll wait for all the images to be loaded. As jAndy says in the comments underneath my answer, it would have to be `DOMContentLoaded`

Comment: @Pekka: I was not sure if that works everywhere; I would recommend a library instead if the images matter.